# applicationWillEnterForeground called on restarting iphone ?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one of my iPhone apps running. Now i switch off my iPhone and restart it.I re-open the same app now. My question is will applicationWillEnterForeground method be called when i re-open the app after restarting?Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not but applicationDidBecomeActive will be called. This method is called every time the app is started or brought back up.

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting so people know what solved the problem

Comment: `applicationDidBecomeActive` will also be called in case user dismisses a `UIAlertView` or Swipes up the notification pane so it can't be a direct substitute to `applicationWillEnterForeground`. Consider placing your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well as `applicationWillEnterForeground `

Answer (score 0):

applicationWillEnterForeground is only called when the app returns from background not when it launches. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidBecomeActive`  is called when you open your application. It does not matter for restarting or not.

However `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called when you open your application when it is open in the background.

Hope this information will be helpful. Good luck!